# How to get ACF data from WooCommerce customers for order export

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, wpallimport

On a Wordpress-Shop I use WooCommerce (WC) with Advenced-Custom-Fields (ACF)
and WP-All-Import (WPAI) + WP-All-Export (WPAE).

I added a ACF field *CustomerNumber* to the WC-Customer (which enhanced the WP-User).
On the WPAI-XML-Import I set the *CustomerNumber* with a value from a ERP.
So all customers have a unique *CustomerNumber*.

I now need to export the WC-Orders (to import them in the ERP again).
The Order-XML must include the *CustomerNumber* from the Customer belongs to the Order.

As I see, the other standard fields from the customer – like name and address – are copied automatically to the order (by WooCommerce itself).

**My question is now:** How I have to do this for the ACF’s?
Did I have to do this by code on my own? Adding the same AC-fields to the WC-Order and hook into the order checkout and copy the values from the customer to the order?
Or is there some kind of setup which do that and which I did not recognize?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I did not really found an answer.
My current solution is now as I described it in my question.

I added a new rule for these acf to also make them available on the orders.
Then I added a hook to new created orders, determine the acf from the user and copied the necessary values into the order acf.

```
function di_woocommerce_new_order( $order_id ) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    if ( !$order ) return;

    $customer_id = $order->get_customer_id();
    if ( !$customer_id ) return;

    $customer = new WC_Customer($customer_id);
    if ( !$customer ) return;

    $customer_number = $customer->get_meta('customernumber');
    if ( !$customer_number ) return;

    // add customer number
    $order->add_meta_data('customernumber', $customer_number);

    // update order modified timestamp
    $order->add_meta_data('order_last_updated', current_time( 'mysql' ));

    $order->save_meta_data();
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'di_woocommerce_new_order', 10, 1);
```